# Issues with socket and server in C (Name or service not known error)

Tags: c, sockets, error-handling, server, client

I am working on a client/server program that is supposed to take user input (two integers) and allow the user to calculate those to receive an answer.

When I run my program there seems to be an issue with either connecting to the client or opening the directory and I'm not sure what it could be. I'm entirely new to setting up servers and utilizing directories to read and write .txt files to.

Here are the parts of code that I think might be wrong and causing the issues I am facing, which is the program asks for a port number to connect to (2000 is what is recommended to use) so I enter that and then nothing happens.

```
  //  PURPOSE:  To run the server by 'accept()'-ing client requests from
//  'listenFd' and doing them.
void        doServer    (int        listenFd)

{
  /* Application validity check: */

  /* Server clients: */
  pthread_t     threadId;
  pthread_attr_t    threadAttr;
  int           threadCount = 0;
  int *iPtr;

  /* YOUR CODE HERE: */
  while(1)

  {

    /* Accept connection to client: */
    int connfd = accept(listenFd, NULL, NULL); //if I change this to getServerFileDescriptor (another function within the code, it will continuously loop through threadNumbers and do nothing as well).

    /* Malloc memory for two integers: */
    iPtr = (int *)calloc(2, sizeof(int));    

    /*Put file descriptor in the first space: */
    iPtr[0] = listenFd; // or just listenFd not sure

    /* put threadCount into the second space and increment: */
    iPtr[1] = threadCount++;

    /* Creates detached thread for handleClient and passes the address of iPtr */
    pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&threadAttr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_create(&threadId, &threadAttr, handleClient, (void*)iPtr);

    pthread_join(threadId, NULL); 
    pthread_attr_destroy(&threadAttr);


   }

}
void* handleClient(void* vPtr)
{
  /* Read command: */
  char  buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
  char  command;
  int   fileNum;
  char  text[BUFFER_LEN];
  int   shouldContinue  = 1;
  int threadNum;
  int fd;

  /* Cast void* vPtr back to an int */
  int *iPtr = (int *)vPtr;

  /* Assign file descriptor to a local value named 'fd'*/
  fd = iPtr[0];
  /* Assign thread number to local value named 'threadNum'*/
  threadNum = iPtr[1];

  free(iPtr);

  while  (shouldContinue)
  {
    memset(buffer,'\0',BUFFER_LEN);
    memset(text  ,'\0',BUFFER_LEN);

    read(fd,buffer,BUFFER_LEN);
    printf("Thread %d received: %s\n",threadNum,buffer);
    sscanf(buffer,"%c %d \"%[^\"]\"",&command,&fileNum,text);

    /* YOUR CODE HERE: */

    if(command == DIR_CMD_CHAR)
    {
        /* 1. Open the current directory (named "."). If an error occurs then just send STD_ERROR_MSG back to the client: */
        DIR* dirPtr = opendir(".");
        struct dirent* entryPtr;

        /* If error occurs send STD_ERROR_MSG to client: */
        if ((dirPtr = opendir (".")) == NULL) {
        {
          write(fd, STD_ERROR_MSG, sizeof(STD_ERROR_MSG));
          //return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* Read as many entries that will fit into BUFFER_LEN 
        put as many entries into the buffer and send the buffer to client
        d_name=entryPtr into the bufffer using strcat_s,
        make sure buffer starts empty
        buffer[0]='\n';
        add new line char using stringcat "\n"
        make sure do not go over buffer lengh */

        if (dirPtr)
        {
          while ((entryPtr = readdir(dirPtr)) != NULL)
          {

            buffer[0]='\0';

            int i;
            int sizebuf = sizeof(buffer);

            for (i = 0; i < sizebuf; i++)
            {
            strcat(buffer,entryPtr->d_name);
            strcat(buffer,"\n");
            }
          }
        }
          /* 3. Close directory */
        closedir(dirPtr);
    }
```

Here's how the correct output should look.

$ ./mathClient  Machine name [localhost.localdomain]? (I just pressed enter)

Port number? 2000

What would you like to do:

(1) List files

(2) Read a math file

(3) Write a math file

(4) Calculate a math file

(5) Delete a math file

(0) Quit

Your choice? 1

Sending "l"
0.bc

Here are the instructions for the code that I am having trouble with.

**Implementing doServer(int listenFd) (10 Points):**

doServer() should have a loop in which it waits for a client to connect to listenFd. When a client does, it should:

- malloc() enough memory for 2 integers
- put the file descriptor from accept() in one of those spaces
- put the value of threadCount in the other space, and increment threadCount
- Make a detached thread to handle this new client. I called my function    handleClient(), but you may call yours whatever. Pass the address of your malloc()-ed array.
- The loop should then go back for another accept().

**void* handleClient(void* vPtr) (10 Points):**

(Or whatever you call your function that runs a thread for the client.)
The thread id and the file descriptor are passed, but they come in as a void* pointer.
Use another pointer to cast back to int*
Save the file descriptor and thread number in local vars
free() the memory
Print the thread number and do a loop like this:

```
 //  II.B.  Read command:
  char  buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
  char  command;
  int   fileNum;
  char  text[BUFFER_LEN];
  int   shouldContinue  = 1;

  while  (shouldContinue)
  {
    text[0] = '\0';

    read(fd,buffer,BUFFER_LEN);
    printf("Thread %d received: %s\n",threadNum,buffer);
    sscanf(buffer,"%c %d \"%[^\"]\"",&command,&fileNum,text);

    // YOUR CODE HERE
  }
```

It read()s a line of text from the client into buffer[], and parses the line into a command character, fileNum integer, and quote-delineated text[] string. (The fileNum and text[] may or may not be given, depending upon the value of command.)

Then do the following operations based upon the value of command. Except for QUIT_CMD_CHAR I strongly recommend using a different function for each!

When the function ends just have it do:

```
 printf("Thread %d quitting.\n",threadNum);
  return(NULL);
```

**command == DIR_CMD_CHAR (15 Points):**

Open the current directory (named "."). If an error occurs then just send STD_ERROR_MSG back to the client.
Copy as many entries that will fit into a buffer of length BUFFER_LEN. Be sure to put a separating '\n' after each entry.
Close the directory.

Any help would be appreciated, if you need the full code I could send that to you if that would help.

EDIT: Here are two additional functions, one called getPortNum() and another called getServerFileDescriptor() which address receiving a port number and setting up sockets for the connection. Additionally I included the main() which utilizes these.

```
//  PURPOSE:  To decide a port number, either from the command line arguments
//  'argc' and 'argv[]', or by asking the user.  Returns port number.
int     getPortNum  (int    argc,
                 char*  argv[]
                )
{
  //  I.  Application validity check:

  //  II.  Get listening socket:
  int   portNum;

  if  (argc >= 2)
    portNum = strtol(argv[1],NULL,0);
  else
  {
    char    buffer[BUFFER_LEN];

    printf("Port number to monopolize? ");
    fgets(buffer,BUFFER_LEN,stdin);
    portNum = strtol(buffer,NULL,0);
  }

  //  III.  Finished:  
  return(portNum);
}


//  PURPOSE:  To attempt to create and return a file-descriptor for listening
//  to the OS telling this server when a client process has connect()-ed
//  to 'port'.  Returns that file-descriptor, or 'ERROR_FD' on failure.
int     getServerFileDescriptor
                (int        port
                )
{
  //  I.  Application validity check:

  //  II.  Attempt to get socket file descriptor and bind it to 'port':
  //  II.A.  Create a socket
  int socketDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, // AF_INET domain
                    SOCK_STREAM, // Reliable TCP
                    0);

  if  (socketDescriptor < 0)
  {
    perror(THIS_PROGRAM_NAME);
    return(ERROR_FD);
  }

  //  II.B.  Attempt to bind 'socketDescriptor' to 'port':
  //  II.B.1.  We'll fill in this datastruct
  struct sockaddr_in socketInfo;

  //  II.B.2.  Fill socketInfo with 0's
  memset(&socketInfo,'\0',sizeof(socketInfo));

  //  II.B.3.  Use TCP/IP:
  socketInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;

  //  II.B.4.  Tell port in network endian with htons()
  socketInfo.sin_port = htons(port);

  //  II.B.5.  Allow machine to connect to this service
  socketInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  //  II.B.6.  Try to bind socket with port and other specifications
  int status = bind(socketDescriptor, // from socket()
            (struct sockaddr*)&socketInfo,
            sizeof(socketInfo)
           );

  if  (status < 0)
  {
    perror(THIS_PROGRAM_NAME);
    return(ERROR_FD);
  }

  //  II.B.6.  Set OS queue length:
  listen(socketDescriptor,5);

  //  III.  Finished:
  return(socketDescriptor);
}


int     main        (int    argc,
                 char*  argv[]
                )
{
  //  I.  Application validity check:

  //  II.  Do server:
  int       port    = getPortNum(argc,argv);
  int         listenFd  = getServerFileDescriptor(port);
  int         status    = EXIT_FAILURE;

  if  (listenFd >= 0)
  {
    doServer(listenFd);
    close(listenFd);
    status  = EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }

  //  III.  Finished:
  return(status);
```

Comment: Nevermind, I edited the original post and included them.

Comment: Hi, could you add a description of the protocolo that are you implementing between Server and Client? It is because i see a possible problem with this line: `sscanf(buffer,"%c %d \"%[^\"]\"",&command,&fileNum,text);`.